# From indirect to directed graph using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I want to convert an indirect graph to a directed graph using python. here is my code .what should I change to get a directed graph?.

I am loading the following adjacency matrix from graph.txt (without the letters representing the column headers nor row names):

```
   A, B, C, D, E
A  1, 1, 0, 1, 0
B  0,-1, 0, 1,-1
C -1, 0,-1, 1, 0
D  0, 1, 0, 0, 0
E -1, 1, 1, 1,-1
```

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx  # version 2.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

f = np.loadtxt ('graph.txt')
ad=[]
for x in f:
    ad.append(x)
print(ad)
df = pd.DataFrame(ad, columns = ['A','B','C','D','E'], index = ['A','B','C','D','E'])
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, bbox = dict(fc="lightgreen", ec="black", boxstyle="circle", lw=3),
    width=2, arrowsize=30)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: How will you decide the direction of each edge?

Comment: according to the incidence matrix :
`
'   A, B, C, D, E
A1, 1,0 ,1 ,0
B 0,-1,0,1,-1
C -1,0,-1,1,0
D 0,1,0,0,0
E -1,1,1,1,-1
`'
the edge must be directed from ligne to column

Comment: @farahlana Please add more information to your question. What is the content of `graph.txt`?